# selected processor does not support `swp x1,x1,[x0]'

Tags: c++, assembly, arm

I try to use swp instruction to implement atomic swap.

```
asm volatile ("swp %[newval], %[newval], [%[oldval]]"
        : [newval] "+r" (newval), [oldval] "+p" (oldval)
        :
        : "memory");
```

when I compiling the code (using `g++ main.cpp -o main -march=armv8-a`). I got the following error message.

```
/tmp/cc0MHTHA.s: Assembler messages:
/tmp/cc0MHTHA.s:20: Error: selected processor does not support `swp x1,x1,[x0]'
```

The ARM machine I use is with armv8, /proc/cpuinfo is like this (It's a SMP machine with 16 cores, information of others processors is the same besides the first line.)

```
processor   : 0
model name  : phytium FT1500a
flags   : fp asimd evtstrm aes pmull sha1 sha2 crc32
CPU implementer : 0x70
CPU architecture: 8
CPU variant : 0x1
CPU part    : 0x660
bogomips    : 3590.55
CPU revision    : 1
```

`g++ --version` outputs

```
g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.9.1-16kord6) 4.9.1
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

I'm getting the following errors when using ldrex/strex instructions

```
/tmp/ccXxJgQH.s: Assembler messages:
/tmp/ccXxJgQH.s:19: Error: unknown mnemonic `ldrex' -- `ldrex x0,[x0]'
```

Can anyone explain me why and where this error comes and how to deal with this error? The machine does not support SWP or I should add some parameters(maybe -march) on compile command to indicate the CPU architecture?

Comment: The `swp` and `swpb` instructions were removed from the ARM architecture. Use `ldrex/strex` for atomic swaps.

Comment: Is this `__sync_val_compare_and_swap` ([link](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.0/gcc/Atomic-Builtins.html))?  Why not use the atomic, and let the compiler sort things out?

Comment: @EOF I tried `ldrex/strex` and got similar error message. And, where can I find instructions my cpu supports?

Comment: @DavidWohlferd: gcc4.9 supports the `__atomic` built-ins, and recent version of gcc deprecate the `__sync` builtins.  The manual says new code should use `__atomic` builtins, instead of `__sync`.  Also, there's a plain `exchange` builtin, as well as CAS.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need ([and shouldn't use](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/DontUseInlineAsm)) inline assembly for this.

Use a gcc builtin:  [`type __atomic_exchange_n (type *ptr, type val, int memorder)`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fatomic-Builtins.html#g_t_005f_005fatomic-Builtins) or C++11 `std::atomic` for this, so the compiler can use the best instruction sequence for the target CPU, based on your `-mcpu=` command line option and whether you're building for 64-bit or 32-bit ARM (or x86), etc. etc.  Also, the compiler understands what you're doing and can optimize accordingly.

```
// static inline
int xchg_gcc(int *p, int newval) {
    int oldval = __atomic_exchange_n(p, newval, __ATOMIC_SEQ_CST);
    //__atomic_signal_fence ( __ATOMIC_SEQ_CST);

    return oldval;
}
```

For ARM64 and ARM (32-bit with `-mcpu=cortex-a72`) with gcc5.4, this compiles to what you want ([Godbolt compiler explorer](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,source:'//+static+inline%0Aint+xchg_gcc(int+*p,+int+newval)+%7B%0A++++int+oldval+%3D+__atomic_exchange_n(p,+newval,+__ATOMIC_SEQ_CST)%3B%0A++++//__atomic_signal_fence+(+__ATOMIC_SEQ_CST)%3B%0A%0A++++return+oldval%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A%0A%23include+%3Catomic%3E%0A//+static+inline%0Aint+xchg_stdatomic(std::atomic%3Cint%3E+*p,+int+newval)+%7B%0A++++//atomic_signal_fence(std::memory_order_seq_cst)%3B++//+equivalent+of+asm(%22%22:::%22memory%22)%0A++++int+oldval+%3D+p-%3Eexchange(newval,+std::memory_order_relaxed)%3B%0A++++//atomic_signal_fence(std::memory_order_seq_cst)%3B++//+equivalent+of+asm(%22%22:::%22memory%22)%0A++++return+oldval%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Astd::atomic%3Cint%3E+xa%3B%0Aint+x%3B%0Aint+y,+z%3B%0A%0Avoid+reordering_test+()+%7B%0A++++y+%3D+1%3B++//+clang4.0+for+x86+optimizes+this+out+(by+moving+it+to+after+the+exchange),+with+mo_relaxed+and+no+fences.%0A++++//+seq_cst+on+the+exchange+stops+clang,+even+with+no+fences.%0A++++//+gcc+doesn!'t+reoder+even+then.%0A%0A++++int+tmp+%3D+1%3B%0A++++tmp+%3D+xchg_gcc(%26x,+1)%3B%0A++++//tmp+%3D+xchg_stdatomic(%26xa,+1)%3B%0A++++y+%3D+2%3B%0A%7D%0A'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:32.24438942829932,l:'4',m:100,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:aarchg54,filters:(___0:(),b:'0',commentOnly:'0',directives:'0',intel:'0',jquery:'3.2.1',length:1,prevObject:(___0:(sizzle1502968292536:(undefined:(legend:!(5,0,'1')))),length:1,prevObject:(___0:(jQuery3210093120048859145041:(display:''),sizzle1502968292536:(undefined:(legend:!(5,0,'1')))),length:1))),options:'-std%3Dgnu%2B%2B11+-Wall+-O3',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'ARM64+gcc+5.4+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)',t:'0')),k:33.12272790206467,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:arm541,filters:(___0:(),b:'0',commentOnly:'0',directives:'0',intel:'0',jquery:'3.2.1',length:1,prevObject:(___0:(sizzle1502968292536:(undefined:(legend:!(75051,0,'1')))),length:1,prevObject:(___0:(jQuery3210093120048859145041:(display:''),sizzle1502968292536:(undefined:(legend:!(75051,0,'1')))),length:1))),options:'-std%3Dgnu%2B%2B11+-Wall+-O3+-mcpu%3Dcortex-a72',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'ARM+gcc+5.4.1+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%233)',t:'0')),k:34.632882669636004,l:'4',m:71.25683060109289,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang400,filters:(___0:(),b:'0',commentOnly:'0',directives:'0',intel:'0',jquery:'3.2.1',length:1,prevObject:(___0:(sizzle1502968292536:(undefined:(legend:!(10,0,'1')))),length:1,prevObject:(___0:(jQuery3210093120048859145041:(display:''),sizzle1502968292536:(undefined:(legend:!(10,0,'1')))),length:1))),options:'-std%3Dgnu%2B%2B11+-O3',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+clang+4.0.0+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)',t:'0')),header:(),l:'4',m:28.74316939890711,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:34.632882669636004,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),l:'2',m:100,n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4)):

```
.L2:   ## This is the ARM64 version.
    ldaxr   w2, [x0]
    stlxr   w3, w1, [x0]
    cbnz    w3, .L2
    mov     w0, w2      # This insn will optimize away after inlining, leaving just the retry loop
    ret
```

Or if you just want atomicity but don't need ordering wrt other operations, then use `__ATOMIC_RELAXED` instead of `__ATOMIC_SEQ_CST`.  Then it compiles to `ldxr` / `stxr`, instead of the acquire/release version of the LL/SC instructions.

For the 32-bit version, if you don't specify a `-mcpu` or `-march`, it calls library functions because it doesn't know what to use for exchange.

I'm not sure if `SEQ_CST` for the `__atomic_exchange` builtin orders with respect to non-atomic things the way `asm volatile("":::"memory")` does; if not you might need fences as described below for C++11 `atomic_signal_fence`.

---

or use this portable C++11 version, which compiles to the same asm:

```
#include <atomic>
// static inline
int xchg_stdatomic(std::atomic<int> *p, int newval) {
    atomic_signal_fence(std::memory_order_seq_cst);
    int oldval = p->exchange(newval, std::memory_order_seq_cst);
    atomic_signal_fence(std::memory_order_seq_cst);  // order WRT. non-atomic variables (on gcc/clang at least).
    return oldval;
}
```

`atomic_signal_fence` is used as an equivalent of `asm("":::"memory")`, to block compile-time reordering with non-`atomic` loads/stores (but without emitting any instructions).  This is how gcc implements it, but IDK if that's required by the standard of just an implementation detail in gcc.

In gcc at least, `atomic_signal_fence` orders operations on "normal" variables, but `atomic_thread_fence` only orders operations on `atomic` variables.  (Shared access to non-`atomic` variables from multiple threads would be an undefined-behaviour data race, so gcc assumes it doesn't happen.  The question here is whether the standard requires `signal_fence` to order non-`atomic` operations along with `atomic` and `volatile` accesses, because the guarantees about what you can safely access in signal handlers are quite weak.)

Anyway, since signal_fence compiles to no instruction, and is only blocking reordering that we want `exchange()` to block anyway, there's no harm.  (Unless you *don't* want `exchange()` to order your non-shared variables, in which case you shouldn't use signal_fence).

---

**`swp` is supported but deprecated in ARMv6 and ARMv7**.  [ARM's docs say](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dht0008a/CJHBGBBJ.html) that it increases interrupt latency (because `swp` itself is not interruptible).  Also,

> In a multi-core system, preventing access to main memory for all processors for the duration of a swap instruction can reduce overall system performance.